# Irreducibility of a polynomial over integers in two variables: proof or reference (for proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients, in $x$ and $y$.

Suppose $f(x,y)$, thought of as polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ satisfies

- it is primitive;
- it is irreducible.

Is it true that $f(x,y)$, considered as polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[y]$ is irreducible? If yes, can one state line of arguments? Also, why primitive condition is inserted above?

(This was used by Patric Morandi, in an example of a subfield $L$ of $k(t)$, function field over a field $k$, where $[k(t):L]$ is finite.)

Comment: Can you add the link concerning $k(t)$?

Comment: What you wrote is always true, because we have an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x][y]\cong\mathbb{Z}[y][x]$. So irreducibility in these rings is the same thing. Now, if $f$ is also primitive then Gauss lemma tells us that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x][y]$ if and only if it is irreducible in the field of fractions $\mathbb{Z}(x)[y]$.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, your first statement is "if..then..."?

Comment: No, I fixed the comment.